# Build Ionic application failed because of Crosswalk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, crosswalk

Suddenly, I start to get this error:

```
C:\Users\andrey.shedko\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BBN.Mobile\BBN.Mobile>ionic run android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\andrey.shedko\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BBN.Mobile\BBN.Mobile\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js" "C:\Users\andrey.shedko\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BBN.Mobile\BBN.Mobile"
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\SDK
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_73
No target specified, deploying to emulator
No emulator specified, defaulting to BBN
Waiting for emulator...
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x30000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Booting up emulator (this may take a while)......BOOT COMPLETE
null
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
   > Could not find any version that matches org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/
         https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/Android/SDK/extras/android/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/Android/SDK/extras/android/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/
         file:/D:/Android/SDK/extras/google/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml

         file:/D:/Android/SDK/extras/google/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.638 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""C:\Users\andrey.shedko\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BBN.Mobile\BBN.Mobile\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b "C:\Users\andrey.shedko\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BBN.Mobile\BBN.Mobile\platforms\android\build.gradle" -PcdvBuildArch=x86 -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

I did tried many times remove and add android platform as well as remove and add Crosswalk browser, but without any success.
Could you advise what to do please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please try to modify the `config.xml` in the root directory of your project. You can see the configuration about the version of Crosswalk.

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_beta:18+" />
```

change it to:

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library:18+" />
```

Comment: Is this something that we'll have to do from now on since this preference wasn't required before?

Comment: Kyle, I suppose that's just wasn't updated in documentation, so we need just check this.

Answer (score 0):

Using version 19, which is now out of BETA, will solve other `appcompat:4+` errors as well

`<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_beta:19+" />`