# ionic2 can not build due to cross walk plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic2

After 3 days of struggling , I am not able to install ionic2. Actually it works for androids with version `4.4.2`  and above (in versions less than this, shows a blank screen, a common problem in forum or github issue part). For working in android ex. `4.2.1` , I found out that I should install **cross walk plugin**. But after that, my app didn't build anymore.

I found different solutions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33675539/4055329) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37604610/4055329). But again, the same errors.
My error while running: `ionic build android` :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:16+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:16+.
         > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/or
g/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/xwalk/xwalk_core
_library/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/5.15
3.35.248] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 27.432 secs

 option to get more log output.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:16+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:16+.
         > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/or
g/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/xwalk/xwalk_core
_library/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/5.15
3.35.248] failed: Connection timed out: connect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.
```

**Any idea?**

And  one more question. Why ionic2 doesn't support android less than version `4.4.2` ?

Comment: Have you also installed *Local Maven repository for Support Libraries* from *Extras* as well? That fixed this issue for me. If it helps you too, I'll post that as an answer to help other users with the same issue.

Comment: @sebaferreras There is no `Local Maven repository` in SDK manager. Some one has told it's the same of `Android support library` and `Google repository`

Comment: @sebaferreras Also I installed all of the items in `Extras` , but again the same error.